# enabling/disabling javascript for alternate style sheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, stylesheet, switch-statement

I have two style sheets for the page I'm working on. When the alternate style sheet is selected i need to run an extra function to get the effect I desire. So my question is, how can I write the javascript to only execute this block of code when the alternate style sheet is active?

The css is switched via two buttons and styleswitcher.js like so:

```
<ul class="viewbuttons">
<li><a class="threedview" href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;">3D View</a></li>
<li><a class="twodview" href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('alternate'); return false;">2D View</a></li>
</ul>
```

and as far as the javascript goes, i've taken the alternate style sheet specific code (twodview) and placed it within a click function to be activated when the style sheet is switched

```
$("a.twodview").click(function(){
all my terrible noob code
});
```

so this obviously works for the first time it is switched to the 2dview, but upon switching back the code remains. What I am currently looking for is how to set a function along these lines:

```
$("a.threedview").click(function(){
remove all my terrible noob code activated by the twodview
});
```

the first option I explored was trying to define the active stylesheet as a variable in a while loop, but much to my astonishment the  in the head don't really change using styleswitcher.js so I don't understand how it is switching the css (magic i presume)

This brings me back to trying to use .click() events as seen above, any suggestions?

Thanks all.

update:

```
$("a.twodview").click( function() {
    $('img.small01').off('mouseenter');
    $('div#makeMeScrollable01').off('mouseleave')
    $('img.small02').off('mouseenter');
    $('div#makeMeScrollable02').off('mouseleave')
    $('img.small03').off('mouseenter');
    $('div#makeMeScrollable03').off('mouseleave')
    });
$("a.threedview").click( function() {
    $('img.small01').on('mouseenter');
    $('div#makeMeScrollable01').on('mouseleave')
    $('img.small02').on('mouseenter');
    $('div#makeMeScrollable02').on('mouseleave')
    $('img.small03').on('mouseenter');
    $('div#makeMeScrollable03').on('mouseleave')
    $('div#booma').off('click');
    });
$("a.twodview").click( function() {
    $('div#booma').click( function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("div#makeMeScrollable01").addClass("currentslide");},2100);
    setTimeout(function(){$("div#makeMeScrollable01").appendTo("body");},2100);
    $("div#makeMeScrollable01").smoothDivScroll("enable");
    setTimeout(function(){$("div#makeMeScrollable01").smoothDivScroll();},2100);
    setTimeout(function(){$("img.small01").hide();},2100);
    });
});
```

So i've figured out how to kind of toggle the hover/click functionality between the 3D view and the 2D view, the problem is that the .on() portion that should rebind hoverIntent() when switched back to the 3D view doesn't work.

Maybe the problem is in hoverIntent()? separating the .off() into mouseenter and mouseleave works fine though so I'm not sure that is the case.

I feel as if my .on() is the right method but not implemented correctly, any suggestions?

Comment: Is the extra functions you're trying to run depend on the same classes? Why don't you add an extra class and use that as the selector?

Comment: That sounds very promising, but let me make sure we are on the same page. Using the addClass with the twodview.click() and the removeClass with the threedview.click() right? I'm working on it right now, thanks!

Comment: hmmm, the classes are adding/removing fine, but it won't execute the code (i'm assuming the code is attempting to execute before the class is added)

Comment: Yes, something like $("foo").click(function() { $(this).addClass("bar"); }); Then you can target that in your styles .bar { /* Styles */ }   Should be good :}

Comment: .toggleClass(); will also work depending on your event.

Comment: Add the extra selector to the html element. Then run the function using that class as the selector?

Comment: It's a no go as of yet. I've done some research to see if i need to use a second document.ready() function or something to get the browser to re-execute the code with the current classes but i've come up with nothing so far. The classes toggle on/off fine, but the code that uses those added classes will not fire :/

Comment: Are you able to add the markup directly in the element? e.g. <p class="firststyle secondstyle"></p> $(".secondstyle").click(function(){});

Comment: yea it adds just fine, the problem is using it as a selector after, i think i need to use the .on() event to get it to work correctly, which I am studying up on right now.

Comment: update: I have found the rather simple and obvious solution to turning off the portion of code necessary, via the .off() method, but I cannot turn it back on.

Comment: Well keep pluckin away at it! You'll get it! :}